# Python Virtual Environment on TeamCity agent

Tags: python, linux, teamcity

I'm facing an issue on TeamCity where I have a build agent with Python 3.8 installed, and I need to run Python scripts that require newer version of Python. Unfortunately, I cannot update Python from 3.8 to 3.10 on this agent and there is no docker on the agent. To work around this, I tried to use a Python virtual environment.

Here's what I did:

1. I created a virtual environment on my local machine.
2. I uploaded the virtual environment directory to my repository.
   In my TeamCity build step, I added the following commands:
   `source venv/bin/activate   python main.py`
   The activation of the virtual environment `source venv/bin/activate` appears to run without any errors. However, when I execute python main.py, it still uses Python 3.8 from the agent, not the Python within the virtual environment. Also when I add `echo $(pip -V)` after activation, it outputs path to Python from the agent.

Is there a way to correctly activate the virtual environment and execute my Python script from virtual environment on the TeamCity agent? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried doing it manually via ssh and see if it works?

there is also a PYTHONPATH environment variable that you can set to the new venv

or u can use full path for python3.10 when u call script after activate venv
/%env.WORK_DIR%/venv/bin/python3 main.py

Comment: Using full path for python actually works. Thank you very much. I still feel like storing and using a virtual environment on a repository is not the best idea and I need to find a better solution in the future.